# MuleSoft anypoint-cli Error: Invalid property format, expected name:value but was {propertyName}

Tags: powershell, mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

I'm trying to deploy an API to MuleSoft Cloud Hub using anypoint cli (anypoint-cli) from PowerShell.

When I am passing property with a dot in the name as a string as per line 93 in the below screenshot, it works fine.

[image]

But When I assigned the exact same value to a PowerShell variable (line 90) and passed to anypoint cli from variable (line 93), it starts giving me “Error: Invalid property format, expected name:value but was crm” error.

[image]

anypoint-cli complains at first dot which is after crm in the property name ("crm.api.username")
if I remove all the dots from property name and change it to something like crmApiUsername in the PowerShell variable (as per below screenshot), it works fine. MuleSoft is not able to process the request when the property has a dot in its name.

[image]

why I want to pass from the variable: I don't want to hard-code properties in my script, I want to pass properties from my release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Powershell syntax issue, unrelated to Anypoint CLI. Try the solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31167398/721855: put a stop parsing symbol `--%` before the properties.

Comment: Thanks @aled for the response. I tried --% before $propertiesVar but I don't think PowerShell is parsing dot, it's passing it to anypoint cli as is because anypoint-cli now complaining % being invalid option ("Invalid option: '%'"). 

I have also tried setting --% at different places but it doesn't seems to work.